# Is there a machine interface (CLI) to GCC that emits errors in a way easy for a library to parse?

Tags: gcc, compiler

I searched google for "libgcc", but that seems to be a non-standalone gcc private library. Does anybody know what I'm looking for? At least, is there a reliable parser for gcc error output or all of it?

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html for tuning the format of gcc's diagnostic messages.

Comment: In particular [the part about `-fdiagnostics-format`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html#index-fdiagnostics-format)

Answer (score -1):

to the best of my knowledge, no, using GCC as library isn't very feasible. GCC errors aren't really hard to parse as is, that's why your IDE might still allow you to jump to the errors in files.

Anyways, if you need to build files, and interact with the errors you encounter on the way, llvm/clang was specifically designed with that in mind.

If you want to have something that offers you the interface that someone would need who's writing a code editor to get syntax highlighting, error display, cross-referencing, macro expansion etc., you will want to look at LSP (language server protocol); there's clangd which offers the server side for C/C++, and there's many clients that make use of it – VS Code, neovim-lsp, emacs-lsp, …

Comment: my IDE is a buggy piece of junk unfortunately :/ it just hangs all the time in a loop and misbehaves when I pass it commands. That's part of the reason why I use CLI almost exclusively. Thx for the tiny hint in the right direction though. LSP seems interesting for other reasons.

Comment: Hey, at no point did I say anything about your IDE! I said you could use the functionality that *an IDE might use*.

Comment: @moFEAR Maybe you need a better IDE.  See also: [Jetbrains - CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)

Comment: @eyoung100 that's what I'm using. either way, could you stick to the topic? this isn't about any IDE.